# Why is stepping back in a debugger hard?

Tags: debugging

I heard a few times that stepping back in a debugger is hard. Why is that? Is it that the memory overhead would be to big? For me it sounds as simple as saving all previous data in ram or to disk and restoring it when you step back. Of course it would be slow if it would have to read from disk but it would be definitely useful. So I assume there is something more to it than I'm thinking of. If overhead is to big for the whole history it would be already useful to be able to just step back a few steps ~5.

Comment: How much more would you pay for a debugger that did that? Does that cover the developer cost? Many debuggers already give you the opportunity to rerun statements.

Comment: Ah I see so it's mainly an economic problem, not a technical one?

Comment: Yes, the memory overhead (or developing an efficient representation that avoids that overhead) is a very major problem.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth could you elaborate a bit? Is it so hard that it's nearly never be gonna used, or could it become available in the future with more memory? Do you know examples of studies or similar?

Comment: The search phrase you're looking for is "time travel debugger" :)

Comment: Thank you exactly :) Sometimes it's hard to know the concise words for what you are looking for.